# Why append a vector to another vector is not allowed here?

Tags: c++, vector

I am appending a vector to another vector using the method (c++):

```
a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

It works, but if `b` is got from a member function, then it won't work anymore, say

```
vector<point> const line::returnAVectorOfPoints() const
{
    vector<point> pts;
    // Do something
    return pts;
}
```

Then this time, when I tried to (something like this)

```
a.insert(a.end(), returnAVectorOfPoints().begin(), returnAVectorOfPoints().end());
```

I got a segv. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you shouldn't return a `const` value, since that prevents it being moved from.

Comment: Which const? I thought the more const the better

Comment: `vector<point> const` as the return type. Usually `const` is good; but on a return type it's evil.

Comment: then why my code still works??? :) You mean I should never return a const type?

Comment: Indeed, you should never return a `const` type. Return values are often assigned to variables, and for efficiency you'd want to do that by moving, rather than copying, where possible. `const` prevents moving, and forces copying. The code will still work (as long as the type is copyable); but it might be less efficient than the same code using move semantics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a vector by value in `line::returnAVectorOfPoints()`, so these two iterators are incompatible:

```
returnAVectorOfPoints().begin(), returnAVectorOfPoints().end()
```

They point to two different, temporary, objects.

You could store the return value in a temporary variable:

```
auto v = returnAVectorOfPoints();
a.insert(a.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
```

As an aside, note you shouldn't return a `const` value. It inhibits move semantics, and this can be quite costly.

Comment: @Daniel This one: `vector<point> const ...`. This one is a silly `const`, but it might have made some sense in some contexts before C++11.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your:

```
line::returnAVectorOfPoints()
```

returns each time new instance as temporary value, change to:

```
vector<point> vec = returnAVectorOfPoints();
a.insert(a.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're referencing two different, temporarily-created vectors. Try

```
auto pts = returnAVectorOfPoints();
a.insert(a.end(), pts.begin(), pts.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also modify the signature to return a ref.

It avoids an unnecessary copy of your vector

```
vector<point>& const line::returnAVectorOfPoints() const
```

Comment: in this current example, returning a reference to pts will result in a dangling reference. The returned value, pts, goes out of scope immediately after being returned, so there is nothing around to return a reference to.

Comment: Agree. This is useful to return a vector member not a local variable

Answer (score 1):

pts is being created on the stack.  When the method returns pts goes out of scope.

try something like this:

```
vector<point> &line::returnAVectorOfPoints(vector<point> &pts) const
{    
    // Do something
    return pts;
}
```

You would call the method like this

```
vector<point> a;
returnAVectorOfPoints(a);
```

This way the vector is external to the method so it can't go out of scope.

I believe the reason it won't work as you wrote is because vector does not have a copy constructor that would allow the compiler to create an intermediary copy of pts before it goes out of scope.  Even if vector did have a copy constructor creating that intermediary copy would be an expensive computational process.

Passing a class in by reference avoids unnecessary copies.

Comment: @Daniel well, you can't return a reference to a local variable, and in your code sample `pts` is local. But in the end it really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I prefer to pass in a scratchpad class by reference the way I did in my example.  As far as I can tell all the other suggestions will still result in a crash because they haven't addressed the scope issue in the method.

Comment: @SerendipityDoDa: No, returning a local variable by value won't cause a crash (as long as it's correctly movable, as `vector` is). The copy or move should be elided for a function as simple as this, so it should be no less efficient than your version. Your version has one issue that returning a value doesn't: what should happen if the caller's vector already has something in it?

Comment: Yes the vector passed in would have to be emptied before calling the method if say one was to put the code in a loop.  I don't see how returning the vector won't result in a copy though.

Comment: "the vector passed in would have to be emptied before calling the method" - so that's one more thing to document, and one more thing that the caller can get wrong, compared to returning a vector. Google "return value optimisation" (also known as "copy elision"), or read C++11 12.8/31, to find out why returning a vector won't result in a copy. (Even if elision fails, in C++11 it will be moved, by adjusting a couple of pointers, rather than copied).